# Command 'generate' not found, compiling with rebar

Tags: http, path, erlang, rebar, cowboy

I am following this blog:
http://maplekeycompany.blogspot.se/2012/03/very-basic-cowboy-setup.html

In short, I am trying to compile an application with rebar just as the person in the blog.
Everything goes smoothly until I want to run the command:

```
./rebar get-deps compile generate
```

This then give me the following errors and warnings,

```
> User@user-:~/simple_server/rebar$ ./rebar get-deps compile generate
> ==> rebar (get-deps)
> ==> rebar (compile) Compiled src/simple_server.erl Compiled src/simple_server_http.erl src/simple_server_http_static.erl:5:
> Warning: behaviour cowboy_http_handler undefined Compiled
> src/simple_server_http_static.erl
> src/simple_server_http_catchall.erl:2: Warning: behaviour
> cowboy_http_handler undefined Compiled
> src/simple_server_http_catchall.erl WARN:  'generate' command does not
> apply to directory /home/harri/simple_server/rebar Command 'generate'
> not understood or not applicable
```

I have found a similar post with the same error:

[Command 'generate' not understood or not applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343630/command-generate-not-understood-or-not-applicable)

I think the problem is in the reltool.config but do not know how to proceed, I changed the path to the following:  {lib_dirs, ["home/user/simple_server/rebar"]}

Is there a problem with the path? How can rebar get access to all the src files and also the necessary rebar file to compile and build the application?

Comment: Ensure that at least one directory pointed in rebar.config as `{sub_dirs, ...}` contains reltool.config for release that you trying to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your directory structure and its contents are arranged so that rebar knows how to build everything in your system and generate a release for it. Your directory structure should look like this:

```
project
   |
   -- rel
   |
   -- deps
   |
   -- apps
       |
       -- myapp
       |    |
       |    -- src
       |    -- priv
       |
       -- another_app
```

The `rel` directory holds all the information needed to generate a release, and the `apps` directory is where the applications that make up your project live. Application dependencies live in the `deps` directory. Each app such as `myapp` and `another_app` under the `apps` directory can have their own `rebar.config` files. While two or more such applications are possible here, normally you'd have just one and all others would be dependencies.

In the top-level `project` directory there's also a `rebar.config` file with contents that look like this:

```
{sub_dirs, ["rel", "apps/myapp", "apps/another_app"]}.
{lib_dirs, ["apps"]}.
```

If necessary, you can use rebar to generate your apps from application skeletons:

```
cd apps
mkdir myapp another_app
( cd myapp && rebar create-app appid=myapp )
( cd another_app && rebar create-app appid=another_app )
```

If an application has dependencies, you'll have to add a `rebar.config` to its directory and declare each dependency there. For example, if `myapp` depends on application `foo` version 1.2, create `apps/myapp/rebar.config` with these contents:

```
{deps,
 [{foo, "1.*", {git, "git://github.com/user/foo.git", {tag, "foo-1.2"}}}]
}.
```

When you run `rebar get-deps`, rebar will populate the top-level `deps` directory to hold all dependencies, creating `deps` if necessary. The top-level `rebar.config` can also declare dependencies if necessary.

You also need to generate a node, necessary for your releases:

```
cd ../rel
rebar create-node nodeid=project
```

You then need to modify the `reltool.config` file generated by the previous step. You need to change

```
{lib_dirs, []},
```

to

```
{lib_dirs, ["../apps", "../deps"]},
```

and just after the line `{incl_cond, derived},` add `{mod_cond, derived},` so that releases contain only the applications needed for correct execution.

Next, wherever the atom `'project'` appears, you need to replace it with the applications under the `apps` directory. For our example, we'd change this part:

```
{rel, "project", "1",
 [
  kernel,
  stdlib,
  sasl,
  project
 ]},
```

to this:

```
{rel, "project", "1",
 [
  kernel,
  stdlib,
  sasl,
  myapp,
  another_app
 ]},
```

and change this part:

```
{app, project, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}]}
```

to this:

```
{app, myapp, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}]},
{app, another_app, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}]}
```

You might also need to add the line:

```
{app, hipe, [{incl_cond, exclude}]},
```

to exclude the `hipe` application since sometimes it causes errors during release generation or when trying to run the release. Try without it first, but add it if you see errors related to `hipe` when generating a release, or if attempts to run the generated release result in this sort of error:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot load',elf_format,get_files}}
```

you'll need to add it.

With all this in place you can now execute:

```
rebar get-deps compile generate
```

and you should be able to successfully generate the release. Note that running `rebar generate` at the top level rather than in the `rel` dir will result in a harmless warning like this, which you can ignore:

```
WARN:  'generate' command does not apply to directory /path/to/project
```

Finally, you can run the release. Here's how to run it with an interactive console:

```
$ ./rel/project/bin/project console
Exec: /path/to/project/rel/project/erts-6.2/bin/erlexec  -boot /path/to/project/rel/project/releases/1/project -mode embedded -config /path/to/project/rel/project/releases/1/sys.config -args_file /path/to/project/rel/project/releases/1/vm.args -- console
Root: /path/to/project/rel/project
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.2  (abort with ^G)
(project@127.0.0.1)1>
```

or you could run `./rel/project/bin/project start` to start it in the background. Run `./rel/project/bin/project` with no arguments to see all available options.